# Filtering a dataframe using isin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is composed from a shapefile that looks like this:

```
STATEFP COUNTYFP    COUNTYNS    AFFGEOID    GEOID   NAME    LSAD    ALAND   AWATER  geometry
1661    21  149 00516927    0500000US21149  21149   McLean  06  653906322   9735021 POLYGON ((-87.49992 37.63927, -87.49835 37.642...
3001    38  055 01034232    0500000US38055  38055   McLean  06  5466428288  563110618   POLYGON ((-102.38570 47.80618, -102.38567 47.8...
3082    17  113 01784833    0500000US17113  17113   McLean  06  3064861155  7562638 POLYGON ((-89.26939 40.59433, -89.26902 40.594...
```

This is just a couple of rows from a much larger dataframe. Now, say I want to select these specific 3 rows from the large dataframe. Specifically, I want to select them based on their GEOID. So I create a list with those specific GEOIDS.

```
codes2=[21149,38055,17133]
```

Now let's try and filter the dataframe using isin.

```
df[df['GEOID'].isin(codes2)]
```

Output:

```
STATEFP COUNTYFP    COUNTYNS    AFFGEOID    GEOID   NAME    LSAD    ALAND   AWATER  geometry
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Check `df['GEOID'].unique()`. My guess they are strings: `['21149', '38055', '17133']`

Comment: Good catch. This solved the issue.